# Array to string conversion exception when using PHPUnit HTML Coverage

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm having an issue that seems to be related to the `--coverage-html` functionality in PHPUnit (I'm using version 4.8.0, though I've encountered it with other versions, too). When I leave it enabled, all tests fail with `Array to string conversion` in the console.

I've been debugging a bit and it seems to be related to this piece of code:

```
// vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream/src/Token/Stream.php:437-441
$this->addFunctionToMap(
    $class . '::' . $name,
    $tmp['startLine'],
    $tmp['endLine']
);
```

The `$class` variable is a one-item `array` with the name of one of my classes, though obviously, a string is expected.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening, and what I can do to fix it?

*Edit:* I noticed people are getting this message when making a mistake with mocking, this also happens for me with mock-less tests

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, this is a regression that was introduced in a new version of php-token-stream.

A pull request has been submitted.

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-token-stream/pull/55